# Test Automation Using Java Selenium - Using JavaMail to check a confirmation email - Doesn't get mail if email arrives few seconds late

Tags: java, selenium, jakarta-mail, ui-automation

So, I've just written my first test into an existing automation framework, for a user registration journey.

What the code does is register a user on the front end, and then use javaMail to check for an email with a specific subject in the background, not through the UI.

7/10 times it works OK, but I notice, on the first few runs in a day it fails, because the email arrives a few seconds late. I have made various amendments to my code to loop if no message found etc, nothing seems to be working.

The exact error that I get in the test is "index 0 out of bounds for length 0", which basically means that the arrayList wasn't populated, so yeah, question is, why isn't it populating..

Here's my getMessageBySubject() method, is there anything blaringly obvious that I'm doing wrong? -

```
public Message[] getMessagesBySubject(String subject, boolean unreadOnly, boolean nonZero, int maxToSearch) throws MessagingException {
        Map<String, Integer> indices = getStartAndEndIndices(maxToSearch);

        Message messages[];
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        do {
            messages = folder.search(
                    new SubjectTerm(subject),
                    folder.getMessages(indices.get("startIndex"), indices.get("endIndex")));

            if (unreadOnly) {
                List<Message> unreadMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();
                for (Message message : messages) {
                    if (isMessageUnread(message)) {
                        unreadMessages.add(message);
                    }
                }
                messages = unreadMessages.toArray(new Message[]{});
            }
        } while (messages.length == 0 && nonZero && System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 20000);

        return messages;
    }
```

This is the call in the actual test class -

```
public void checkEmailConfirmation() throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Message email  = Arrays.asList(emailUtils.getMessagesBySubject("Account confirmation for " + registrationTitle + " " + registrationFirstname + " " + registrationLastname, true, true, 5)).get(0);
        String link = emailUtils.getUrlsFromMessage(email, "confirm").get(0);
        assertThat("Confirmation link not populated",link != null && !link.trim().isEmpty());
        basePage.goToURL(link);
        assertThat("Not logged in successfully!", myAccountPage.loginSuccessful());
```

We use gradle for our project, these are the javaMail packages we are using -

```
   compile 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:smtp:2.0.0'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. I have spent way too long pulling my hair out over this test :'(

Answer (score 0):

Got around this, and works everytime now, turned out we needed to open and close the folder so created a method to do that here -

```
    public void refreshFolder() throws MessagingException {
        folder.close();
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    }
```

The getMessagesBySubjectMethod now looks like -

```
    public Message[] getMessagesBySubject(String subject, boolean unreadOnly, boolean nonZero, int maxToSearch) throws MessagingException {
        Map<String, Integer> indices = getStartAndEndIndices(maxToSearch);

        Message messages[];
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        do {
            refreshFolder();
            messages = folder.search(
                    new SubjectTerm(subject),
                    folder.getMessages(indices.get("startIndex"), indices.get("endIndex")));

            if (unreadOnly) {
                List<Message> unreadMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();
                for (Message message : messages) {
                    if (isMessageUnread(message)) {
                        unreadMessages.add(message);
                    }
                }
                messages = unreadMessages.toArray(new Message[]{});
            }
        } while (messages.length == 0 && nonZero && System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 20000);

        return messages;
    }
```